# How to get the default text of a Django form field validation error message?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing unit tests for a Django application using the test client (django.test.client.Client).

I have a page on my application with a form that contains an EmailField.  In my unit test, I want to submit form data containing an invalid email address, and then inspect the response content to verify that it contains error message text for an invalid email address.

But how do I know what text to look for?

In general, how do I get the default error messages for a particular field type?

Answer (score 2):

I finally came up with this:

```
>>> from django.core.validators import EmailValidator
>>> EmailValidator.message.strip()
u'Enter a valid email address.'
```

It satisfies my immediate need, but it seems like there should be a better solution.